# How can I reference a object value from secret manager in serverless.yml?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, aws-secrets-manager

I am deploying apps to AWS via `serverless`. And need to read values from secretmanager during deployment. I have read this doc: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#reference-variables-using-the-ssm-parameter-store

it shows how to read it:

`custom: supersecret: ${ssm:/aws/reference/secretsmanager/secret_ID_in_Secrets_Manager~true}` 
however, it can be used to read a string value from secret manager. My secret is an object which includes `key/value` pairs. How can I read the `key` inside a secret?

I have tried something like this:

`custom: supersecret: ${ssm:/aws/reference/secretsmanager/secret_ID_in_Secrets_Manager:MY_KEY~true}`

`custom: supersecret: ${ssm:/aws/reference/secretsmanager/secret_ID_in_Secrets_Manager/MY_KEY~true}`

but none of them working.

Comment: Can you try with `${ssm:/aws/reference/secretsmanager/secret_ID_in_Secrets_Manager~true}.keyname`?

Comment: it doesn't work. serverless complains `Trying to populate non string value into a string for variable`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Serverless will resolve the object for you.

Assuming that the content of your `secret_ID_in_Secrets_Manager` looks like this:

```
{
  "foo": "foo",
  "bar": "bar"
}
```

Then if you define your custom variable in `serverless.yml` like this:

```
custom:
  supersecret: ${ssm:/aws/reference/secretsmanager/secret_ID_in_Secrets_Manager~true}
```

Then this will resolve to:

```
custom:
  supersecret:
    foo: foo
    bar: bar
```

You can reference them inside `serverless.yml` by using `${self:custom.supersecret.foo}` and `${self:custom.supersecret.bar}`.

See the [Serverless documentation](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#reference-variables-using-the-ssm-parameter-store) and search for *Variables can also be object, since AWS Secrets Manager can store secrets not only in plain text but also in JSON.*.

Comment: Keep in mind that Serverless Framework is about to switch to a new SSM Variable resolution soon (at the time of the comment it can be manually enabled with `variablesResolutionMode: 20210326`). In this mode, "~true" has to be omitted. Otherwise, it will be considered a part of the secret name