# How can I reference json nested value from secret manager via serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, aws-secrets-manager

I am using `serverless` to deploy to AWS. And I need to read secrets from secret manager. Below is the syntax it supports. It works fine for a string value. If my secret saved as a json, how can I reference the nested value from json?

```
DARKSKY_APIKEY: ${ssm:/darksky-api-key~true}
```

for example, the value is:

````json
{
username: xxx
password: xxx
}
```,

how can I reference the `password` from above syntax?
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I reference a object value from secret manager in serverless.yml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65949994/how-can-i-reference-a-object-value-from-secret-manager-in-serverless-yml)